# Unique constraint on combination of more than two columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables ***book*** and ***page***
I' trying to setup a bidirectional one to many relation between them.

***page*** has unique constraint on multiple columns which isn't working correctly. When i insert book_item with unique page_item it works as its supposed to but when i try to delete the book which should also delete the pages, i get *unique constraint violation exception* which i don't really understand.
i'm using jpa repository to perform insert/delete.

When i remove @UniqueConstraint the delete works but also the constraint doesn't so i don't really understand what i'm doing wrong.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "book_uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "book_uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @Getter
    private UUID id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<Page> pages;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "page", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"book_id", "chapter", "volume", "name"}))
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Page implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "page_uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "page_uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    @Type(type="uuid-char")
    @Getter
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NonNull
    private Book book;

    @Column(name = "chapter", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int chapter = 0;

    @Column(name = "volume", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int volume = 0;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NonNull
    private String name;
}

// Code used for insertion/update /deletion


@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, UUID> {

}


public void test() {
    Book book = bookRepository.findById("9c7b2ab2-1c78-4e9f-adc5-99c7da42a7c6");

    List<Page> pages = IntStream.range(0, 5)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Page(book, "Page" + i, ".png"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    book.setPages(pages);
    bookRepository.save(book);
    bookRepository.delete(book);
```

The error message i get :

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UKOBQWYIY89PIIE6GP2NB4PVQ8W_INDEX_2 ON PUBLIC.PAGE(BOOK_ID, CHAPTER, VOLUME, NAME) VALUES ('acb0bb92-be2f-4dd3-9653-98f8d890e6b4', 0, 0, 'Page0', 1)"; SQL statement:
>
> insert into page (book_id, chapter, extension, name, volume, id) values (?, ??, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: I would not rely on cascading as it performs many SQL queries, and removes entities you may not wish to remove that may be related to other entities. Instead manage it by doing your own DELETE statement, or removing manually.  See for more info https://thoughts-on-java.org/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/. Please post the code that is doing your add/removal of books.

Comment: I've added a simple code snippet which is doing insertion and deletion, when i execute this i get the error mentioned in the post.

Comment: Firsts at all, put @Transactional in your repository then just mapping a method deleteById as javaNoob's suggestes and let that cascade orphan removal does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `deleteById`

```
  deleteById("9c7b2ab2-1c78-4e9f-adc5-99c7da42a7c6");
```

Comment: Error message indicates problem with INSERT, not DELETE

Comment: may be try     @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false,insertable = true)

Comment: It worked with deleteById but as others suggested i had to add @Transnational on my method for it to work with delete(book)